# How to get the user's home timeline with the Twitter Android SDK

Tags: android, twitter

I am in the process of migrating to Twitter's official Android SDK so we can use SSO, but I cannot seem to find a way to load the user's home timeline

The docs don't mention the Home Timeline

But the call is included in the REST interface in the code.
http://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/twitter-core/1.4.2/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/services/StatusesService.html

For now I have created my own class to leverage this call (https://gist.github.com/hansvdg/726e3bebdf3e8622fb57).

Does someone know how to officially get the user's home timeline?